# Room DAO Update how best to handle old unwanted data

Tags: android, sql, insert, android-room, dao

I have a Room table of objects and when I get my network call to refresh the list of objects the items could have been changed. So I need to remove any data that is no longer in the new fetched list.

Pre-Fetch Ids in Table:
|ObjectId|
|:-------|
|1|
|2|
|3|
|4|

Post-Fetch Ids in Table:
|ObjectId|
|:-------|
|1|
|2|
|4|

So Objects removed:
|ObjectId|
|:-------|
|3|

**My Quesiton:** Is the best way to do this just Delete all entries in the table before calling an @insert method or is there another way using the @update that will allow me to simply fetch the new data and remove all the old data that is no longer in the new list of objects? My understanding is that an @update will simply update objects 1,2 & 4 and leave 3 as it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a list of id's (assuming these uniquely identify the rows) then you could update according to the list and delete (before or after the updates) according to the list using a `WHERE` clause that utilises [`NOT IN` operator(s)](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_in_and_not_in_operators)

- Note that the deletion should be done via an **`@Query`** not `@Delete` e.g. `@QUERY("DELETE FROM the_table WHERE id NOT IN(:the_id_list);"`

This would minimise the number of deletions. Deletiong and Updates should be done within a single [transaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction).

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think about the @transaction method.